# editing the 400 google plus error

Tags: google-api, google-plus

I have the following error screen related to **Google Plus Oauth authentication**:

[image]

My question is not related with the error message but with editing the content of the message.
As clear from the image that, there are some additional lines mentioned below the `Error:origin_mismatch` line, namely, starting from `Application` and `You can email the developer ....`. I am wondering if I can edit these lines and mention my own custom message over there?

I tried using Firebug and search my documents(code), with the `id` that is visible but unable to find anything related to that in my code. Has anyone edited the same thing before or know where exactly I can find that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The application details are edited from [console.developers.google.com](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This was something new I just learned. However, I don't see anything related to the `400 Error` screen that I posted in my question. Could you tell me how can I edit that information?

Comment: I know about the origins. I am looking to edit `"Application"` and `You can email the developer of this application` part of the window as shown in the image above.

Comment: You edit the values of those via the link I included in my answer.